# Selectively splitting a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, split

New to Perl.

I need to parse a report that look like this:

```
2012-05-29@emaillocalpart@emaildomain@customerid@errormessage@messageid
```

I used:

```
my @fields = split(/@/, $line, 6);
```

Most of the time it works fine, but sometimes the error message will contain an email address and all text after the @ symbol on that email until the end of the string will end on my message id.

I thought about checking for the amount of @s and have a conditional parsing, but is there a better way?

EDIT:

The desired output is a list of strings, with the error message containing whatever came in it (including an occasional email address).

Since there are other applications using the same report I cannot change the separator or escape the output.

Sample lines on the report:

```
2012-05-29@joedoe@example.com@AB99-5@440 4.4.1 Some error occurred@XYZ35
2012-05-29@foobar@invalid.com@ZZ88-6@550 5.1.1 <foobar@invalid.com>... User Unknow@GGH93
2012-05-29@barfoo@invalid.com@YY88-0@550 5.1.1 barfoo@invalid.com no such user@GGH93
```

Expected contents of @fields after parsing line 1:

```
2012-05-29
joedoe
example.com
AB99-5
440 4.4.1 Some error occurred
XYZ35
```

And after parsing line 2:

```
2012-05-29
foobar
invalid.com
ZZ88-6
550 5.1.1 <foobar@invalid.com>... User Unknow
GGH93
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired output is? A list of strings?

Comment: that's a little difficult design there, as your separator **may** be part of the data. If you have access to the report generator I would think about escaping the error message or changing the separator char...

Comment: Can you give an example of the special error message with the email address?

Comment: Are you storing the line with the `@`'s in a variable in your script? And please clarify your error, maybe with the contents of `fields`.

Comment: Wait so you *want* an error message?? Please try to write your answer as clearly as possible.

Comment: Ok, this question is finally coming together :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to daxim's answer, but another way of writing it:

```
my $re = '^' . '([^@]*)@'x4 . '(.*)@([^@]*)$';
my @fields = $line =~ /$re/;
```

You may also want to do some error checking here:

```
my @fields = $line =~ /$re/ or die "can't parse '$line'";
```

Comment: Heads up: I had a bug, my intention was for the two email parts to be parsed as one token, hence the output of our programs are different now.

Comment: @daxim, but that seems to be the desired result, at least as demonstrated in the questions examples.

Comment: Choosing this solution as it is the easiest to apply to my specific problem and the regex looks clear. Running sample here: http://codepad.org/rhTLTMBR

Answer (score 4):

If $teststr contains, for example: '2012-05-29@emaillocalpart@emaildomain@customerid@error@me@ssage@messageid';

the following code:

```
my @fields2=split('@',$teststr);
my @finalfields=@fields2[0 .. 3];
my $finalat=$#fields2-1;
my $errormessage=join('@',@fields2[4 .. $finalat]);
push(@finalfields,$errormessage);
push(@finalfields,$fields2[$#fields2]);

print Data::Dumper->Dump([@finalfields])."\n";
```

gives the following output:

```
$VAR1 = '2012-05-29';
$VAR2 = 'emaillocalpart';
$VAR3 = 'emaildomain';
$VAR4 = 'customerid';
$VAR5 = 'error@me@ssage';
$VAR6 = 'messageid';
```

Apologies - it's rather a verbose solution. You can also do the same in one regular expression:

```
$teststr=~/(.[^@]*)@(.[^@]*)@(.[^@]*)@(.[^@]*)@(.*)@(.[^@]*)/;
print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n$6\n";
```

Comment: Just tested, works nicely, although my real report has 16 fields instead of 6, so the one liner will look a bit uglier.  :)

Comment: @CleberGoncalves my answer will work for any number of fields, without a cumbersome regex. Just fyi :-)

Answer (score 1):

This properly parses optional email addresses:

```
$str = '5-29@foobar@invalid.com@ZZ88-6@550 5.1.1 <foobar@invalid.com>... User Unknow@GGH93';
#$str= '2012-05-29@joedoe@example.com@AB99-5@440 4.4.1 Some error occurred@XYZ35';

$str =~ s/(\<[^\>]+\>)/!!/; # replace an email address with !!
$email = $1; # store the email

@fields = split(/@/,$str); # split on @

s/!!/$email/ foreach (@fields); # find the old !! and replace with the email address

print STDERR map { "$_ \n" } @fields; # print fields to standard error
```

See it working [here](http://codepad.org/VSTuksBJ). This assumes you only have one optional email. With a little work it could be modified to work for a string with any number of `< >` delimited emails.

Comment: Edited my question, when trying out your solution I found that the report may also contain email address that are not delimited by <>. The error message is pretty much free text. Will go with the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this would be to change `@` to another, extremely less common delimiter like `;;;;`

Comment: From OP's question: "Since there are other applications using the same report I cannot change the separator or escape the output."